# How to fix "Error: Delegation forbidden" from an originated address?

Tags: delegating, delegation

When trying to delegate from my Tz1 address I get "Error: delegate deletion is forbidden"

I think I registered this address as a baker in the past.  Is there a way to un-register?

Answer (score 1):

No, once you register an address as a delegate it's not possible to un-register it or change its delegation. Hopefully this will change in the future.